# How can I add styling to a sidebar area based on the widget it contains?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a WordPress theme from scratch for the first time, and I just created a custom widget for the footer that contains the contact info for the site. I'm using Flexbox for the layout of up to four footer columns, and I want the column containing this custom widget to have `flex-basis: 2;` so that it's wider than the others at times.

How can I add a class name to whichever column the user places the custom widget in?

**EDIT: I said `flex-basis` when I meant `flex-grow`.**

Answer (score 0):

Rather then add a class to the column, maybe the best thing is to find the name of the class that is already there, and then add the CSS code.

To find the class:
Using Chrome, inspect the element.  In the console window, it will show what the class name is.
Then go into your Dashboard > Appearance > Editor and add your custom css code.

For example, on of my websites,
I used the left sidebar for widgets and dropped in some generic widget boxes in there.  I used css to add the style i wanted.  So for the titles, I wanted them to look like blue boxes with white letters.  The code looks like this:

```
.widget-title {background-color: #004165; padding: 5px; color: #ffffff; margin-bottom: 15px;}
.widget-title {color: #ffffff !important; font-weight: normal !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm actually developing the code myself, but I've found I need a little help. Once my theme is complete, the user will have the ability to add widgets to four footer columns. I just want to ensure that whichever column holds the "Contact Info" widget displays wider than the other columns, if there are only three active columns.

For example, if the user places this contact info widget in Column 1, then puts other widgets into 2 more columns--totaling 3 columns--the `flex-basis: 2;` will display the column twice as wide as the other 2 columns.

[1/2] [1/4] [1/4]